# Extracting specific characters from middle of string in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have something like this

```
st1 <- "psi-mi:pcgf1_human(display_long)|uniprotkb:RING finger protein 68(gene name synonym)|uniprotkb:Nervous system Polycomb-1(gene name synonym)|uniprotkb:PCGF1(gene name)|psi-mi:PCGF1(display_short)|uniprotkb:NSPC1(gene name synonym)|uniprotkb:RNF68(gene name synonym)"
```

My expected output

```
"PCGF1"
```

I am looking to get characters appear before (gene name) which is PCGF1

Comment: before `"(gene name)" ` and after  `"uniprotkb:" ` ?

Comment: thanks for the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using `sub()`:

```
name <- sub(".*:([^:]*?)\\(gene name\\).*", "\\1", st1)
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: There is no point using `gsub` since you are performing a single replacement operation. `sub` is enough.